# Issues with connecting to an Adafruit FLORA board

Tags: serial, usb, adafruit

I just bought a new Adafruit Flora board, and I haven't been able to get it working successfully. When I plug it into a USB port, the board seems to be getting power (the green PWR LED is illuminated), but there is no other output from the board. The Arduino IDE also does not recognize the board (the "port" menu under "Tools" is grayed out), and I have tried to connect to it on both Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) systems with the appropriate drivers/packages installed (including the Windows drivers and the board manager add-on in both installations of the Arduino IDE). I've also verified that the USB cable I'm using can handle data.

Previously, I was able to at least get the board to be recognized in the IDE on my Linux machine, and the red LED did light up, but after disconnecting it doesn't light up anymore (unless I try to reset the board, which makes the red LED pulse a few times).

Anything that I can try to get it recognized in the IDE?

Edit: I'm able to see the board pop up under "ports" in the IDE immediately after I hit the reset button on the board. However, as soon as the red LED stops pulsing (I think this means that the board is finished rebooting), it disappears from the list of available ports. It's also mounting under /dev/ttyACM0, not the usual /dev/ttyUSB0.

Comment: /dev/ttyACM0 is OK. upload Blink while the port is visible

Comment: @Juraj Yep, just tried this and it works. Strange. Thanks though!

Comment: it is not strange. the ATmega32u4 on board has a built in USB handled by the Arduino core linked with your sketch. if your sketch doesn't run, the USB is not handled. reset starts the bootloader which handles the USB while running.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like whatever code was running on the Flora was corrupted. As soon as I hit the reset button, the board would momentarily pop up in the Arduino IDE, and after doing this a few times, I managed to upload the "Blink" sketch while the board was visible to my system. After that the board started working normally. It reports its name as "Adafruit FLORA" under "get board info", and the serial monitor/onboard LED work just fine.